# Add column value in the spark dataset on the basis of a condition

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

```
public class EmployeeBean implements Serializable {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Long salary;

    private Integer age;

    // getters and setters

}
```

Relevant spark code:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[2]").appName("play-with-spark").getOrCreate();
List<EmployeeBean> employees1 = populateEmployees(1, 10);

Dataset<EmployeeBean> ds1 = spark.createDataset(employees1, Encoders.bean(EmployeeBean.class));
ds1.show();
ds1.printSchema();

Dataset<Row> ds2 = ds1.where("age is null").withColumn("is_age_null", lit(true));
Dataset<Row> ds3 = ds1.where("age is not null").withColumn("is_age_null", lit(false));

Dataset<Row> ds4 = ds2.union(ds3);
ds4.show();
```

Relevant Output:

**ds1**

```
+----+---+----+------+
| age| id|name|salary|
+----+---+----+------+
|null|  1|dev1| 11000|
|   2|  2|dev2| 12000|
|null|  3|dev3| 13000|
|   4|  4|dev4| 14000|
|null|  5|dev5| 15000|
+----+---+----+------+
```

**ds4**

```
+----+---+----+------+-----------+
| age| id|name|salary|is_age_null|
+----+---+----+------+-----------+
|null|  1|dev1| 11000|       true|
|null|  3|dev3| 13000|       true|
|null|  5|dev5| 15000|       true|
|   2|  2|dev2| 12000|      false|
|   4|  4|dev4| 14000|      false|
+----+---+----+------+-----------+
```

Is there any better solution to add this column in the dataset rather than creating two datasets and performing union?

Comment: @vindev makes sense. Please add it as an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same can be done using `when otherwise` and `withColumn`.

```
ds1.withColumn("is_age_null" , when(col("age") === "null", lit(true)).otherWise(lit(false))).show()
```

This will give the same result as the `ds4`.